# How to keep whitespace before comma?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to get a certain column from a dataframe but I can't because of how Python processes Strings. My problem is that Python automatically deletes spaces before comma. For example, the column I'm trying to get is "Invasive Pneumococcal Disease, Age LT 5† , Probable" but Python will process it as "Invasive Pneumococcal Disease, Age LT 5†, Probable" such that I couldn't access that given column. I couldn't simply change the column name because of other complications. Is there a way I can enforce Python to leave my String as is and not delete that whitespace?

Input:

```
df["Invasive Pneumococcal Disease, Age LT 5† , Probable"]
```

Output:

```
'Invasive Pneumococcal Disease, Age LT 5†, Probable'
```

Comment: Python does not do any such thing.

Comment: I assume you are using Pandas, and I believe that's a Pandas issue, not Python. Try assigning that text to a variable and printing it right after, it won't behave like that.

Comment: I just tried the replace() to enforce the space and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I could just use replace()

```
>>>sample = "Invasive Pneumococcal Disease, Age LT 5† , Probable"
>>>sample = sample.replace('†', '† ')
```

Answer (score 0):

[(([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+)](https://regex101.com/r/0leyUh/1) this will find all the Unicode and ASCII words.

So the logic is, find all ASCII/Unicode words which have a literal whitespace `\s` followed by a comma then again a literal whitespace `\s`, after finding that replace the first captured group with just a comma followed by a white-space.

[The regex](https://regex101.com/r/CkMcrE/1) for finding the above.

Here's the code:

```
import re
str = "Invasive Pneumococcal Disease, Age LT 5† , Probable"

def normalize_comma_endings(matchobj):
    ascii_unicode_words_pattern = r"(([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+)"
    base_word = re.findall(ascii_unicode_words_pattern, matchobj.group(1))
    return "{}, ".format(base_word[0][0])


comma_endings_pattern = r"(([^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+\s,\s)"
res = re.sub(comma_endings_pattern, normalize_comma_endings, str)
print(res)
```